# 3D bar plot with dates, strings and numbers in 3 axes with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have three lists as mentioned below.

```
xx =  ['TT', 'AN', 'AP', 'AR', 'AS', 'BR', 'CH', 'CT', 'DN', 'DD', 'DL', 'GA', 'GJ', 'HR', 'HP', 'JK', 'JH', 'KA', 'KL', 'LA', 'LD', 'MP', 'MH', 'MN', 'ML', 'MZ', 'NL', 'OR', 'PY', 'PB', 'RJ', 'SK', 'TN', 'TG', 'TR', 'UP', 'UT', 'WB']
yy = [datetime.date(2020, 5, 27), datetime.date(2020, 5, 28), datetime.date(2020, 5, 29), datetime.date(2020, 5, 30)]
zz = [7246, 0, 134, 0, 101, 68, 1, 4, 0, 0, 792, 1, 376, 76, 26, 162, 7, 135, 40, 1, 0, 237, 2190, 5, 0, 0, 5, 76, 0, 33, 280, 0, 817, 107, 10, 267, 69, 183, 7254, 0, 128, 1, 97, 149, 10, 34, 0, 0, 1024, 1, 367, 123, 8, 115, 6, 115, 85, 20, 0, 192, 2598, 11, 1, 0, 9, 67, 4, 19, 251, 0, 827, 117, 2, 179, 31, 344, 8138, 0, 85, 0, 177, 174, 0, 17, 0, 0, 1105, 0, 372, 217, 14, 128, 82, 248, 62, 0, 0, 192, 2682, 4, 6, 0, 7, 63, 4, 39, 298, 0, 874, 169, 10, 275, 216, 277, 8304, 0, 131, 1, 128, 206, 0, 32, 0, 0, 1163, 1, 412, 202, 18, 177, 42, 141, 58, 3, 0, 246, 2940, 3, 0, 0, 11, 96, 0, 36, 252, 0, 938, 74, 17, 256, 33, 317]
```

I want to plot bar3d plot using matplotlib in python such that x axis will be **xx**, y axis will be **yy** to plot **zz*, i.e. date wise plotting. Following tutorials, I tried

```
dx = np.ones(len(xx))
dy = np.ones(len(yy))
dz = np.ones(len(zz))   # doubt
ax.bar3d(xx, yy, zz, dx, dy, dz, shade=True)
```

Obviously, I got errors

```
  ax.bar3d(xx, yy, zz, dx=dx, dy=dy, dz=dz, shade=True)
File "/home/vega/anaconda3/envs/tf01/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2365, in bar3d
  np.atleast_1d(x), y, z, dx, dy, dz)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in broadcast_arrays
File "/home/vega/anaconda3/envs/tf01/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 264, in broadcast_arrays
  shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
File "/home/vega/anaconda3/envs/tf01/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 191, in _broadcast_shape
  b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I think I did not understand proper formulation of tuples for bar3D plot. I request any handle to resolve. I scanned earlier questions and hence I believe it is not a repeat question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently doing it wrong. Just follow the official example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html) and you can do something like this. You need to create a 2-dimensional mesh grid of x and y points for each of your bar. Moreover, to create the meshgrids, you have to use numbers and later reset the tick labels to your original strings

```
x = np.arange(len(xx))
y = np.arange(len(yy))

_xx, _yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX, YY = _xx.ravel(), _yy.ravel()

bottom = np.zeros_like(zz)
dx = np.ones(len(XX))
dy = np.ones(len(YY))

ax.bar3d(XX, YY, bottom, dx, dy, zz, shade=True)

ax.set_xticks(range(0, 36, 2))
ax.set_xticklabels(xx[::2])

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(4) + 0.5)
ax.set_yticklabels(yy);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Actually I was suddenly confused on meshgrid generation and also on getting dx, dy for date and strings.